# Will the following sets be convex in the real space $C[a, b]$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

> Will the following sets be convex in the real space $C[a, b]$:
>
> a) polynomials of degree $n$;
>
> b) polynomials of degree not higher than $n$.

A subset $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called convex if it contains, along with any pair of its points $(x,y)$ also the entire segment $[x,y]$:

$$x,y\in M,0\leq\lambda\leq 1\implies \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\in M.$$

A polynomial of degree $n$ in a single variable $x$ can be written in general form

$$a_nx^n+a_{n–1}x^{n–1}+\dots+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=\sum a_i x^i$$

To be honest, I don’t even know where to start. Please give me a hint. And what is the difference between a) and b)? Thank you.

Comment: What is an algebraic polynomial? How is it different from a polynomial?

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry, it's just a polynomial. I translated the question incorrectly from my language.

Comment: If you add two polynomials of degree $n$ will the result necessarily be of degree $n$?

Comment: Both are convex. Just take two arbitrary elements of your set, and check the definition for them.

Answer (score 0):

a) NO. For example take $x^n$ and $-x^n$ then $0=\dfrac{1}{2}(x^n-x^n)$ is not the polynomial of degree $n$.

b) Yes. Notice that $deg(f+g)\leq max\{deg(f),deg(g)\}$.